# Unit test angular form to ensure form cannot be submitted unless required fields are provided

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

Using the test below, I'm seeing that my code coverage sees this:

```
public onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
```

as being executed, even though I have not input data into the `title` textfield .. why is that?

How can I test this kind of logic?

dummy.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: './dummy.component.html'
})
export class DummyComponent {

  public submitted = false;
  public onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
}
```

dummy.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>New Page Form</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #pageForm="ngForm">
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" required [(ngModel)]="model.title" name="title" #title="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="title.valid || title.pristine">
          Title is required
        </div>
      </div>

      <button id="submitNewPage" type="submit" [disabled]="!pageForm.form.valid">Finish</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h2>New page details:</h2>
    <div>
      <div>Title: {{ model.title }}</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button (click)="submitted=false">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

dummy.component.spec.ts

```
it('should create an instance of PageFormComponent', () => {
  fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#submitNewPage').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that is even firing the event in the proper way with that click()? Because as far as i know should be something

```
  describe('your block', () => {
     let submitB;
    beforeEach(() => {
       submitB = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.query(By.css('#submitNewPage'));
       submitB.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
     });

    it('your expectation' () => {})
   })
```